# Get tumblr photo post content via API but arrange it differently for photoset posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, tumblr

I have some code which currently loops through posts on a blog and outputs them as inside a list item as an image with link and caption text if it exists. This works fine, but when I run the code and there are photoset posts each image and caption gets looped as per the photo blog posts.

(So if there are 10 images in a photoset and 1 caption each image and caption gets output 10 times).

Here is my original code which works:

```
// get tumblr posts and embed them. 
var postContent     = $('#tumblr-posts');
var getPosts = {};
getPosts.get = function(){
    var offSet = href * 10;
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/jessicaharby.tumblr.com/posts?limit=11",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            api_key: _site._apiKey,
            tag: 'news',
            offset: offSet
        },
        success: function(results){
            var i = 0;
            while (i < results.response.posts.length) {
                var type = results.response.posts[i].type;
                var photoset = results.response.posts[i].photoset_layout;
                if (type == "photo") {
                    var photos = results.response.posts[i].photos;
                    var linkURL = results.response.posts[i].post_url;
                    var caption = results.response.posts[i].caption;
                    for (var j = 0; j < photos.length; j++) {
                        var imgURL;
                        if (photos[j].alt_sizes[1]) {
                            imgURL = photos[j].alt_sizes[1].url
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
                        postContent.append("<li><img src=" + imgURL + " /><p>" + caption + "</p></li>");
                    }
                i++;
            }
            console.log(results.response);
            postContent.find('a').attr('target','_blank');
        }
    });
}

getPosts.get();
```

I have been trying to write an else if statement which captures the photoset posts. It needs refining but looks like this:

```
else if(photoset != null) {
    for (var k = 0; k < photos.length; k++) {
        var imgURL;
        if (photos[k].alt_sizes[1]) {
            imgURL = photos[k].alt_sizes[1].url
        }else{
            continue;
        }
        postContent.append("<li><img src=" + imgURL + " /></li>");
    }
    postContent.append("<li><p>" + caption + "</p></li>");
 }else{
    console.log('some error')   
}
```

So it should spit out all the images and the one caption at the bottom of the post (so I guess I need these all inside one list item). I am just not 100% sure how to finalise the loops.

Another issue is that if I write an if/else if I think with my current code the first if is true and so the posts will be repeated potentially, or the else if may be ignored.

I have two fiddles which can be experimented with/forked etc;

1) http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/bLveggwk/1/  loops through all posts

2) http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/bLveggwk/3/ only loops through photoset posts.

Apologies that this is not the neatest question. If I am not clear I can make a drawing if that helps!

**EDIT**

Decided to make an image:

[image: Tumblr posts]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to output all the photos from a photoset, then the caption, in one post?

Comment: Yes, and photo posts should be treated as normal. Sorry if it's not very clear @mikedidthis.

Comment: @mikedidthis I ended up making an image after all (each of the white blocks should be an LI hopefully. http://i.imgur.com/OqLu3nd.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the problem well, btw this solution http://jsfiddle.net/1bLrocj1/ works?

significant part:

```
var set = [];
while (i < results.response.posts.length) {
    var type = results.response.posts[i].type;
    var photoset = results.response.posts[i].photoset_layout;
    if (photoset != null) {
        var photos = results.response.posts[i].photos;
        var linkURL = results.response.posts[i].post_url;
        var caption = results.response.posts[i].caption;
        for (var j = 0; j < photos.length; j++) {
            var imgURL;
            if (photos[j].alt_sizes[1]) {
                imgURL = photos[j].alt_sizes[1].url
            } else {
                continue;
            }
            set.push("<li><img src=" + imgURL + " /></li>");
        }
        if (caption) {
            set.push("<li><p>" + caption + "</p></li>");
            var subUl = document.createElement("ul");
            for (var k = 0; k < set.length; k++) {
                $(subUl).append(set[k]);
            }
            postContent.append(subUl);
            set.length = 0;
        }
    } else {
        console.log('some error')
    }
    i++;
}
```

css:

```
ul li {
    padding:20px;
    float:left;
    max-width:550px;
    background:#FFF;
}

ul li:last-child {
    margin:0 1px 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you. I've managed to get this working with photosets and normal photo posts. I had to make one minor tweak, but the points are yours. In your fiddle you are outputting a ul as a direct child of another ul, usually it should be wrapped inside another li to nest properly. But thank you so much I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Ah, I cannot award the bounty until tomorrow!

Comment: Glad to have been helpful :)